# Twilio pass in parameters in the Twilio's HTTP request

Tags: parameters, sms, twilio

I am not sure if it is possible, but I am desperate here. Any suggestion would help.

Our web application sends SMS reminders to our clients to remind them of their events. We want to add a feature that allow users to confirm or delete that event by replying with either 0 or 1. But unfortunately this information it is not sufficient to perform any modification on that event. The user might have 10 events and want to confirm 8 and delete 2. So how could I pass information like event id through the message? Making the user enter the event id is not a practical solution for users.

Comment: can you pass the event ID as part of the message? something like "reply with numbers to confirm attendance: 1 library, 2 party, 3 birthday"

Comment: Yes I can it will be like "reply with 2879345 to confirm that you are attending party with id 2879345".

Comment: So yes, on your side you should store the event ID's in a database or similar, then when you are sending the SMS just send the event ID's in the SMS body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in the comments:

> On your side you should store the event ID's in a database or similar,
>   then when you are [sending the SMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) just send the event ID's in the SMS
>   body.

Example:

> "reply with 2879345 to confirm that you are attending party with id
>   2879345"